# Google app marketplace sdk setup url stopped working

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Till very recently this feature was working where on app installation, the user was either presented an option to do the setup or automatically redirect the browser to the setup url. Now, it completely stopped working. Is anyone experiencing the same? If not, please let me know on how to debug this issue. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there a way to bring this to the attention of google API team quickly.

Comment: Wow this is STILL broken.

Comment: Yeah, it is unbelievable that google would not attend to this issue or   at least acknowledge on this forum which they are suppose to monitor.

Comment: Same issue. Double checked that the Google Apps Marketplace SDK was pointed to my correct Setup URL.  The Chrome console is logging "Unknown RPC service: launchurl" after clicking 'Install App' (app is already loaded on the domain and after installing on a clean domain without the app installed)

Comment: I've searched everywhere for an email address for support but I don't see anything. Anyone monitoring this forum?

Comment: Looks like google fixed the issue. Back on the horse again :)

Comment: This is still broken.

Comment: Not working at all, and it's been only half a year